# Python. import из файла main в один из пакетов

Tags: python, python-import

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть проект, оконное приложение на python. Весь функционал прописал в файле main, но я хочу перенести его в module/data.py, при импорте возникает ошибка: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'. В файле **init**.py корня игры прописал from .main import.. А дальше не особо вникаю что и как.

Comment: А где и как вы его импортируете то? Это важно.

Comment: Я из файла main должен импортировать 3 объекта классов (app, mWindow, sWindow) в файл data.py | main.py находится в коренной папке. Но выдает ошибку, поэтому не могу

Comment: А, понял. Вы в `data.py` импортируете из `main.py`? Не очень хорошо, так не делают. Импортировать нужно наверх из подкаталогов, а не наоборот. Странная у вас зависимость.

Comment: Да, именно так. Тогда как по другому можно реализовать функционал программы? У меня в main создаются экземпляры классов, которые здесь же и запускаются. Получается нужно просто поменять местами

Comment: Обычно в подкаталогах хранят библиотеки, а в корневом `main` - основной код, который подключает эти библиотеки, вызывает их, создаёт объекты, передаёт между модулями и т.д. Как-то так. Создавать объекты можно и в библиотеках, но вызов на это создание и дальнейшие манипуляции должны идти "сверху".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Всё что ниже не является ответом на вопрос, я перепутал и подумал что **main.py** находится в **ui**. В вашем случае надо прописать в data.py:*

```py
import имя_коренной_папки.main
```

---

Для того чтобы в **module/data.py** импортировать **ui/main.py**, можно в **ui/**init**.py** прописать

```py
from .main import *  # или что-то что нужно
```

и в **module/data.py** импортировать директорию

```py
import ui
```

*Если что, исправьте в комментариях, отредактирую ответ.*

Вообще, в вашем конкретно случае заморачиваться с этим не надо (мне кажется этот способ подойдёт когда нужно импортировать много всего из многих файлов). Можно просто импортировать **ui/main.py** в **module/data.py**, то бишь в **module/data.py** прописать

```py
import ui.main
```

Comment: Файл main находиться в коренной папке, папка UI тут не при чем, т.е через файл main я запускаю программу, функционал которой должен быть в data.py

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил.

Comment: Что прописано в data.py?

Comment: там должен быть прописан функционал приложения, грубо говоря, мне нужно импортировать из main само тело приложения (app) и два окна (mWindow, sWindow) для того чтобы все работало, ради этого и была создана эта тема. А вот как сделать это, я не знаю

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: Немного не понял. Как я могу импортировать main из коренной папки, если оно выдает ошибку при  вводе ее названия?

Comment: Значит название коренной папки некорректное, возможно там есть "-" или что-то другое

Comment: К сожалению все равно ошибка, не знаю что уже и делать. Папка всего проекта называется "notes", и все равно выдает ошибку когда импортирую notes.main

Comment: Странно, у меня похожая иерархия папок. Я прописал общую папку в качестве коренной (в вашем случае видимо это notes) и у меня всё сработало.

Comment: Вы даёте достаточно мало данных. Ошибка как-то изменилась?

Comment: Ошибка не изменилась. Я переделаю немного систему, дабы все импортировать в файл main, а не из него. Благодарю за прошлые ваши ответы.